# Disposing Mutex object

Tags: c++, multithreading, garbage-collection, mutex, managed-c++

Working in managed c++ code. A static Mutex object is created like this :-

```
static Threading::Mutex* _mutex;
```

and it is initialized inside the static constructor like this :-

```
_mutex = __gc new Threading::Mutex(); (i.e created an managed object)
```

Now my doubt is whether this mutex object should be disposed using dispose() or close() of Threading::Mutex class? Or it will be automatically disposed by gc since it is an managed object.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The static Mutex would be either disposed by the dispose() or by the OS kernel when the process exits.

In addition, close() disposes the object as well.

Comment: That means for cleaning OS level resources, should i explicitly call :-            _mutex->Close() or _mutex->Dispose() ?